# Computing a relative homology group.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

> For $p_1,p_2 \in \mathbb C P^n$ compute the homology group $H_*(\mathbb C P^n, \{p_1,p_2\}).$

Since $(\mathbb CP^n ,\{p_1,p_2\})$ is a CW pair it follows that $$H_*(\mathbb CP^n, \{p_1,p_2\}) \cong \widetilde {H_*} (\mathbb C P^n/ \{p_1,p_2\}).$$

But how do I compute $H_* (\mathbb C P^n/ \{p_1,p_2\})\ $? Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Use homology long exact sequence for the pair $(\Bbb CP^n,\{x,y\})$. For $0$-th homology: If $X$ be a path-connected space and $A$ be a non-empty subspace of X, then $H_0(X,A)=0$.

Comment: Also, consider reduced homology long exact sequence we have $0\to \widetilde H_1(\Bbb CP^n)=\pi_1(\Bbb CP^n)=0\to H_1(X,A)\to \widetilde H_0(\{x,y\})=\Bbb Z\to \widetilde H_0(\Bbb CP^n)=0$

Comment: @Sumanta can't we say that $\mathbb C P^n / \{p_1,p_2\} \simeq \mathbb C P^n \vee S^1\ $? Since $\mathbb C P^n$ is path connected we can draw a path $\gamma_1$ joining $p_1$ and $p_2$ which is entirely lying on $\mathbb C P^n.$ Let $\gamma_2$ be another path lying outside $\mathbb C P^n$ joining $p_1$ and $p_2$ (here we need path connectedness of the complement of $\mathbb C P^n$ which I am not sure of). Then both the paths are contractible and hence we have the above homotopy equivalence obtained by quotienting out each of the paths.

Comment: @Sumanta according to what you did it turns out to me that $$H_n(X,A) \cong \begin {cases} \mathbb Z & n =1 \\ 0 & \text {otherwise} \end{cases}$$ Am I right?

Comment: @Dey you are right. I did a blunder in computing the relative homology. It should be $$H_m (X,A) \cong \begin{cases} \mathbb Z & m = 1,2,4,\cdots,2n \\ 0 & \text {otherwise} \end{cases}$$ But I don't understand your argument on path-connectedness of the complement of $\mathbb C P^n.$ Can you please be more explicit about it? Thanks.

Comment: By mistake, I deleted my previous comment. Whatever, what I meant there you can think $\mathbb CP^n$ inside $\mathbb CP^{n+1}$ now $\mathbb CP^{n+1}\setminus \mathbb CP^n$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb C^{n+1}$ which is path connected. @Fanatics

Comment: What's ISI? What I mentioned in my previous comment is that you can use the fact that, for a cw pair $(X,A), X/A \simeq X\vee SA$ if $A$ is contractible in $X.$ Also I mentioned that you can think $\mathbb CP^n$ from $D^{2n}.$ I don't know what's wrong in it. Btw, what similarlies you have found, I don't know. But, I try to express what I understand @Fanatics

Comment: @Dey here $A = \{p_1,p_2\}$ is not contractible. Although $SA \approx S^1.$

Comment: @Fanatics contractible in $X$ means that the inclusion map from $A$ is null homotopic.

Comment: @Dey why is it so? By translating appropriately we can think of $p_1,p_2 \in \text {int} (D^{2n})$ where there is no identification involved. Since $D^{2n}$ is convex and hence star convex with respect to the origin in particular we can consider the homotopy $(a,t) \longmapsto (1-t)a,$ $a \in A$ and $t \in [0,1].$ Is that what you mean?